# JQuery, issue with DOM Removal on LI Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, laravel-blade

Before you think this question has been answered before (which it, I guess, technically has), let me point out that any other post in relation to this type of issue is of different context and therefore the answer does not fit my issue.

Anyways, for the sake of simplifying the situation, I have a UL element with a bunch of LIs inside of it which are generated by a foreach loop through the JSON object provided to the page. I want to be able to delete rows. All very standard so far. I have written up some very standard JQuery/JS to handle this task, but for some peculiar reason, part of the script functions correctly while part of it doesn't (the DOM removal part). I've tried writing it at least 4 different ways, using different functions to achieve the task, even have tried moving the statement to different areas of the function, as well as alternate placement of the functions itself.

I also want to say that since I am deleting individual rows, they're all identified by a dynamically generated ID, which (I suspect) is perhaps related to the issue I'm facing.

Here's the code itself, starting with the button to initiate the function;

```
<button type="button" onclick="unsave({{$savedpost->id}})" class="btn float-right btn-dark my-auto" id="unsaveBTN{{$savedpost->id}}">Unsave</button>
```

As you can see there's usage of blade syntax for the dynamically generated ids.

Here's the actual JQuery script that is called by the button

```
            <script defer>
                function unsave(savedID){
                    // /saved/{savedid}/unsave
                    var saved = document.getElementById(savedID);
                    console.log(savedID);
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: '/'+savedID+'/ajax',
                        headers: {
                            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                        },
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function(result) {
                            // append to popupDisplayList
                            if(result.success) {
                                saved.remove();
                                $('#popupDisplayList').append($('<li class="list-group-item alertGroup"><div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert"><strong>Success!</strong> '+result.success+'<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button></div></li>'));
                            } else if (result.error) {
                                $('#popupDisplayList').append($('<li class="list-group-item alertGroup"><div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert"><strong>Error!</strong> '+result.error+'<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button></div></li>'));
                            } else { return }
                        }
                    });
                };
            </script>
```

The script as I have it, is quite obviously not very well optimized, but it's the current state of the script after trying multiple other solutions, at first it was just one script and optimized.

In one rendition of the script, I tried adding a class to the div in the initial function and then deleting it if a variable named success was returned as true, which would happen when the AJAX response came back as result.success. I would then delete all items with that class. Obviously that's a very roundabout way, but I'm getting desperate here.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

Here's the code

```
<li class="pl-4 list-group-item" id="{{$savedpost->id}}">
    <div class="row justify-content-between">
       <div class="row pl-4">
            <img class="img-fit-fluid" src="/storage/images/{{$savedpost->picture_link}}" alt="Saved post image">
            <div class="row flex-column">
                 <h5 class="text-dark pl-5 align-middle">{{$savedpost->name}}</h5>
                 <p class="text-secondary pl-5 align-middle">{{$savedpost->desc_short}}</p>
            </div>
         </div>
      <div class="btn-group" role="group">
           <a href="/{{$savedpost->id}}" class="btn float-right btn-secondary my-auto">View</a>
           <button type="button" onclick="unsave({{$savedpost->id}})" class="btn float-right btn-dark my-auto" id="unsaveBTN{{$savedpost->id}}">Unsave</button>
       </div>
  </div>
</li>
```

Comment: did you get the id in JS using {{$savedpost->id}}?

Comment: can you add ul, li in question?

Comment: can you please explain what you want to achieve with "function unsave{{$savedpost->id}}()" if it is string interpolation, in this case you should only use it to pass argument from the button(which will be you post id), and your function should look something like this **function unsave(savedPostId)**

Comment: Blade is loaded before the front end JS is built, so by the time the JS starts being built all the {{$savedpost->id}} is filled in with the specific ID in question, and yeah no problem give me a second to add the LI

Comment: I've tried passing the ID through as a parameter instead of in the name, no different, it doesn't matter much the manner in which I provide the ID all that really matters is that fact that the .remove() function doesn't execute correctly even though from the client side it looks correct when inspecting it on Chrome.

Comment: let's consider blade does the thing, and your function now looks like **function unsaveSomeSpecificID()** so it will only work for a particular Id, because you are changing the function name itslef, which only exists one's. so you should keep the function name fixed, and pass a dynamic parameter. and put some console logs to see what is working and how.

Comment: The scripts are created inside the foreach as well, so given it's not particularly efficient, it does have a function corresponding to each LI, so yes, I've now changed it to be dynamic but that wasn't the reason for the issue described.

Comment: I've edited the question, now displaying the dynamic function. The issue still persists, as I stated. No clue why someone voted the question down, without any actual person being able to figure out what the issue is, lol.

Comment: `saved.remove()` – if that is supposed to be a call of the jQuery `remove` method - then you need to call it on an actual jQuery collection. Your `saved` here isn’t one - it is just the result of `getElementById`, so it is a HTMLElement object. `$(saved).remove()` should do the trick then. (But I’d be rather surprised, if this did not manifest in the browser console somehow. HTMLElement objects do not have a `remove` method, to my knowledge, so I’d expect to see some sort of error message showing there then.)

Comment: The code as I have it written works as intended, once I click the button a second time. The AJAX call fires both times but only actually removes the element on the second click.

Comment: added answer.. let me know if it is not working..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change Button to:

```
<button type="button" class="btn float-right btn-dark my-auto unsavebtn" data-postid="{{$savedpost->id}}" id="unsaveBTN{{$savedpost->id}}">Unsave</button>
```

Change Script:

```
jQuery("body").on("click",".unsavebtn", function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();

    var postid = jQuery(this).data("postid");
    var thisElem = jQuery(this);

    $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         url: '/'+postid+'/ajaxsave',
         headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
         },
         dataType: 'json',
         success: function(result) {
             // append to popupDisplayList
             if(result.success) {
                  thisElem.parents("li.list-group-item").remove()
                  $('#popupDisplayList').append($('<li class="list-group-item alertGroup"><div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert"><strong>Success!</strong> '+result.success+'<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button></div></li>'));
                  success = true;
             } else if (result.error) {
                   $('#popupDisplayList').append($('<li class="list-group-item alertGroup"><div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert"><strong>Error!</strong> '+result.error+'<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button></div></li>'));
             } else { return }
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: Answer worked for the most part, only change I made is to change the call to the function from outlining an event to listen for to just detecting a click on any item with the class unsavebtn, as the solution as you have outlined above caused a double-click issue for some reason, as in, one click would cause the AJAX to be fired twice, which, since the endpoint given is a toggle switch, was problematic. Everything else was kept the same. Thank you for your solution.

Comment: To show exactly the change I made; `$(".unsavebtn").click(function(){
                    var postid = jQuery(this).data("postid");` instead of `jQuery("body").on("click",".unsavebtn", function(e)
{
    e.preventDefault();
`